# How can I make "commit" abort if there are uncommitted subrepo changes in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

This seems to happen all the time to me: I work on the parent repo. I find and fix a bug in a subrepo. I carry on with parent repo work. I commit the parent repo with a message like "Added feature X". I push.

At this point I notice that the subrepo bugfix got committed and pushed too, with a commit message that has absolutely *nothing* to do with the subrepo.

What’s the easiest way to make myself a "commit" replacement which would refuse to do anything in this situation, pointing out that a subrepo has uncommitted changes? Alternatively, perhaps there’s a setting I can put in my `.hgrc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Upgrade your Mercurial instalation to 2.0 or later
2. Edit your `~/.hgrc` file and add the following option to the `[ui]` section:

   ```
   commitsubrepos = false
   ```

Comment: The `ui.commitsubrepos` config setting was introduced in Mercurial 1.8

Comment: Nice! I googled enough to have convinced myself that there’s no built-in way for this...